# Extended search in excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all rows with the value "00" in column E, if a value of "01" exist in column E, with the same values in column A. Maybe a bit comfusing, but see the setup below.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46000 | x | x | x | 00 |
| 46000 | x | x | x | 01 |

If both values "00" and "01" exists with the same value in column A, the row with "00" in column E needs to be deleted. The list itself is very long with diferent values in column A.

Maybe a Excel guru can help a hand?

I tried to write code with loops and different searches.
Also chatGTP, but it's hard to acurate describe wahts going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if you sort the data by column A then column E and remove duplicates (using column A and E as your duplicate criteria) it will do what you want.  While sorting isn't required, it will speed things up if you do.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed your explanation correct here is a quick macro that will Sort the data by Column A Ascending and then Column E Descending. This will put the duplicate data with the 01 on top.

Then add a helper cell using a `countif` to find duplicates. Making the first part of the range Absolute and the second a relative reference.

| A | b | c | d | e | Helper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46000 | x | x | x | 01 | 1 |
| 46000 | x | x | x | 00 | 2 |

I then filtered by anything `>1` and deleted it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortAndRemove()

Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = oWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lngLR As Long: lngLR = oWS.Cells(oWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Turn off Screen and alert pop ups
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


With oWS
    'Sort data in column A in Ascending order then Column E descending
    With .Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add2 Key:=Range("A2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add2 Key:=Range("E2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        
        .SetRange Range("A1:E" & lngLR)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    'Add a helper cell to see which are duplicates
    With .Range("F2:F" & lngLR)
        .Formula = "=countif($A$2:A2,A2)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    'Filter to everything above 1 and remove
    With .Range("A1:F" & lngLR)
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=">1"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    
    'Delete the helper cell
    .Columns(6).Delete

End With

'Set excel back
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Kavorka.
One problem, now all "00"' lines are counted as 1, and it should only be deleted if there's no "01". So a sinle "00" line should stay and not be deleted.

Comment: Also there can be more than just "00" and "01", also "02" and higher. So only if a projectnumber in column A has a number of "00" in column E (and only that), the row needs to stay. If other numbers in column E exists it needs to be deleted.

Comment: I just tested with sample data and that is just what happened. All the Single "00" lines remained. The macro is set to delete any number Greater then 1. So those single "00" will remain. Can you provide a bigger data set and show the expected result

Comment: I created an excel file with more info.
https://
we.tl/t-v4OwvR4Ifu
The yellow rows should be deleted and the green should stay.

This a a export of our planning software and the 00 line is where first layout is done.
As soon as the complete project has been divided in sub sets (01,02,03 and on), the 00 line can be deleted.

Comment: to add the link, I had to cut it up, so remove the blank inbetween for the correct link.

Comment: Looking at your spreadsheet, Line 60 Project 45824 shows it in green, but on line 68 there is another 45824? Is this something I will have to account for or was this just missed by yourself?